# How to write output from parallel subprocesses to different files

Tags: python, subprocess, output

I have the following python script. How can I log the outputs of each command separately, i.e. one file per each command containing that command's output?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

from subprocess import Popen
import sys

commands = [
    'command1',
    'command2',
    'command3'
]

processes = [Popen(cmd, shell=True) for cmd in commands]

for p in processes:
    p.wait()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set `stdout` parameter to a corresponding file:

```
import shlex
from contextlib import ExitStack # $ pip install contextlib2 (on Python 2)
from subprocess import Popen

with ExitStack() as stack:
    for i, cmd in enumerate(commands):
        output_file = stack.enter_context(open('output%d.log' % i, 'w'))
        stack.callback(Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=output_file).wait)
```

To redirect stderr output from a child process, you could set `stderr` parameter. If `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` then stdout and stderr are merged.

[`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) is used to close the files and wait for already started child processes to exit even if an exception happens inside the `with`-statement e.g., if some command fails to start.